# MFC Ole Server porting to newer version – AfxGetThread returns null

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, porting

I’m currently in the process of porting a suite of MFC C++ applications [MFC OLE Server] from VS 2003 (currently running on Windows XP) to VS 2010 – MFC7.1 (Windows 7).

The particular application that I’m having problems with builds fine [having removed any deprecated functionality], but when I try and run it, both the AfxGetThread() and AfxGetApp() in the function below [in winmain.cpp] return NULL.

```
// MFC AfxWinMain source code

int AFXAPI AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
   _In_ LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

   ASSERT(hPrevInstance == NULL);

   int nReturnCode = -1;
   CWinThread* pThread = AfxGetThread();
   CWinApp* pApp = AfxGetApp();
   …
```

There is documentation on Google about the AfxGetThread() function changing between versions of Visual Studio, and having to implement your own version of AfxGetThread() – but I cannot get the framework to call this function correctly from my app.

If anyone has any ideas that would be great,
Thanks
Jas

Answer (score 0):

From [this msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/06/21/why-afxgetthread-returns-null-in-afxwinmain.aspx), it looks like you need to globally instantiate your derived `CWinApp` like

```
CMyApp theApp;
```

outside your functions.

Alternatively, the code in this [MSDN form answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1f3c7189-ebd3-43ff-baa9-5528114d7290/please-help-on-this-strange-windows-service-only-exception?forum=vcgeneral) suggests that you need to call

```
CWinApp* pApp = AfxGetApp();
```

before caling

```
CWinThread* pThread = AfxGetThread();
```

Comment: Thank you. I had read the msdn blog post and it gave enough details about a possible scenario. But in my code, we already have the global theApp instantiated. The code that I mentioned in my question is from MFC source code for AfxWinMain. Also ours is a MFC Ole server (exe), do you know of any changes around Ole in MFC71 that could cause AfxGetThread to return null?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post a more complate version of your main source so that I can reproduce your problem? [code after `AfxGetThread()` and `AfxGetApp()` can be excluded]

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you did not write your own version of the AfxWinMain.

Your problem has nothing to do with the fact that your app is Ole server.
AfxGetThread will definitely return NULL for any application type, if application’s constructor, hence the base class constructor is not called. It is a place where all values (including current win thread pointer) is set.

I would set breakpoint in the app’s constructor to see if is called **before** AfxWinMain.
It is a shame that MFC code does not check for validity of the CWinThread and CWinApp pointers and allow unhandled exception.